# Android: Which part is programmatically responsible for multiple clients in client server connection

Tags: android, urlconnection

I want to build an app which will transmit data(Long, lat, timestamp and SSID) every 60 seconds to the server in the background when the location changed. The data will be stored in the in the database and in case of request the server will send response back to the user. I want to do that by using HttpURLConnection api  which programmatically steps shall I take in consideration to make my Server deal with multiple clients?Multithreading?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `The data will be stored in the in the database ` of the server? What kind of server do you want to learn multi threading? `programmatically steps` for your server code?

Comment: Its crowdsourcing tracking system for the buses.Yes, the data will be stored in the database of the server since other user will request the server to get specific info about the location of the desired  bus.  I will first try to work on my wamp localhost and then for testing I will need database server.

Comment: You want help but still didn't tell which script language you use for the server.

Comment: @greenapps: I will PHP for the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me try to explain what exactly is the server end behaviour here and what should be the expectations from client and server side.

client end --
U have to fire post/get request after particular duration and you can use alarm manager (in android ) to the same. that would be all at client end.

Server End ---
use `ExecutorService` for thread pooling in your `Servlet`.
in constructor of servlet , initialize it with poolsize, here u have choice of cached pool.or fixed pool ,as per the need of product.

syntax would be something like this--

```
private ExecutorService exectorService;
```

in Constructor--

```
this.exectorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();// Executors.
```

now according to ur request type ..either doGet() or doPost will receive a request ..

so extract the content of request in above methods and on successful extraction send the response success.

create a runnable which will be responsible for all the queries and procedure execution.
and add that runnable to thread pool. like this----

```
processhandler = new ProcessHandler(getServletContext(),targetString);
exectorService.submit(processhandler);
```

that would be all for thread pooling ..

now comes the connectionPooling for database insertion and updation.
I would rather suggest to go through HikariCP for connection pooling.
it is very effective and fast.

hope this helps !
cheers